# How to enlarge an Ellipse in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

How i can enlarge an Ellipse in WPF, preffering using Margins, just like i did in my wrong code :D ? how i can do that, you will understand from the "wrong code"

```
<DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:01" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin" From="789,-189,762,899" To="23,-189,-4,-637"/>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ryn31.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ThicknessAnimation` instead of `DoubleAnimation` :)

Comment: Thanks man, i really worked, any idea how i can make the animation smoother ?

Comment: try `EasingFunction` :) ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee308751(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I tried enlarging an Ellipse by altering Margin values but did not see any visual change.

I see this question already has been answered, in any case, here is an example of how it is possible to animate the height and Width of an Ellipse in WPF using markup in XAML:

```
 <Ellipse Height="100" Width="100" Fill="Blue" Stroke="Black">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="100" To="300" Duration="00:00:02" />
                                <DoubleAnimation RepeatBehavior="Forever"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="100" To="300" Duration="00:00:02" />

                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>

 </Ellipse>
```

Comment: Tnx you too, i will remind this but it worked with Margins too